# In Objection.js, how can I include a virtual column with my query?

Tags: javascript, knex.js, objection.js

I would like to create an `expired_bool` virtual column.

I have the following 3 tables:

**subscriptions**:

| id | duration | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 0.99 |
| 2 | 360 | 1.99 |

**invoices**:

| id | user_id | purchase_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | 2020-01-01 01:21:01 |
| 2 | 42 | 2021-02-19 19:19:19 |

**invoice_items**:

| id | user_id | invoice_id | subscription_id | activation_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | 1 | 1 | 2020-05-15 12:51:51 |
| 2 | 34 | 1 | 2 | 2021-02-20 20:20:12 |
| 3 | 42 | 2 | 1 | NULL |
| 4 | 42 | 2 | 2 | 2021-02-20 20:20:12 |

This is how the `User`, `Invoice`, and `InvoiceItems` tables are modeled in Objection.js:

```js
class User extends Model {
  static get tableName() {
    return "users";
  }

  static get relationMappings() {
    return {
 
      invoices: {
        relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
        modelClass: Invoice,
        join: {
          from: "users.id",
          to: "invoices.user_id",
        },
      },

      invoiceItems: {
        relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
        modelClass: InvoiceItem,
        join: {
          from: "users.id",
          to: "invoice_items.user_id",
        },
      },

    };
  }
}

class Invoice extends Model {
  static get tableName() {
    return "invoices";
  }

  static get relationMappings() {
    return {
      user: {
        relation: Model.BelongsToOneRelation,
        modelClass: User,
        join: {
          from: "invoices.user_id",
          to: "users.id",
        },
      },

      invoiceItems: {
        relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
        modelClass: InvoiceItem,
        join: {
          from: "invoices.id",
          to: "invoice_items.invoice_id",
        },
      },
    };
  }
}

class InvoiceItem extends Model {
  static get tableName() {
    return "invoice_items";
  }

  static get relationMappings() {
    return {
      invoice: {
        relation: Model.BelongsToOneRelation,
        modelClass: Invoice,
        join: {
          from: "invoice_items.invoice_id",
          to: "invoice.id",
        },
      },

      user: {
        relation: Model.BelongsToOneRelation,
        modelClass: User,
        join: {
          from: "invoice_items.user_id",
          to: "users.id",
        },
      },

      subscription: {
        relation: Model.HasOneRelation,
        modelClass: Subscription,
        join: {
          from: "invoice_items.subscription_id",
          to: "subscriptions.id",
        },
      },
    };
  }
}
```

And this is how I'm **Querying** for the user and his/her purchases:

```js
async function getUserAllWithPasswordByIdAsync(userId) {
  try {
    const query = await User.query()
      .findById(userId)
      .withGraphFetched("invoiceItems.subscription")
      .withGraphFetched("invoices")

    return query;
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Just as an aside, the `expired_bool` virtual column is determined by checking the `activation date` of **invoiceItems** and adding the `duration` from the **subscriptions** table, and making sure that date is in the future from today's date.

So in summary, how can I determine if the `invoiceItem` is expired automatically (by use of a virtual column, which should be added to the `invoiceItems` table), and ensure that this is included with my query of `User`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you can't use virtual field to do async operations. Nor can you query based on virtual fields. They are defined entirely in javascript.

So it can be done as follows (using `raw` imported from Objection.js):

```
import objection from "objection";
const { Model, raw } = objection;
...

class InvoiceItem extends Model {
  ...
  static modifiers = {
    expiryInfo(qb) {
      qb.select(
        'invoice_items.*', 
        raw('activation_date + make_interval(days => subscription.duration)').as('expiration_date'),
        raw('activation_date + make_interval(days => subscription.duration) < now()').as('expired_bool'),
      ).joinRelated('subscription')
    }
  }
  ...
}

    const query = await User.query()
      .findById(userId)
      .withGraphFetched("invoiceItems(expiryInfo).subscription")
      .withGraphFetched("invoices")
```

This uses Postgres functions, but the idea remains the same for other databases, though the code inside `raw` may need to be slightly adjusted.

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution would be to add `expiry_date` column to `invoice_items`.

Both `activation_date` and `expiry_date` will be set during subscription activation

```
activation_date = today's date
expiry_date = activation_date + subscription duration
```

**invoice_items**:

| id | user_id | invoice_id | subscription_id | activation_date | expiry_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 | 1 | 1 | 2020-05-15 12:51:51 | 2020-06-14 12:51:51 |
| 2 | 34 | 1 | 2 | 2021-02-20 20:20:12 | 2022-02-15 20:20:12 |
| 3 | 42 | 2 | 1 | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | 42 | 2 | 2 | 2021-02-20 20:20:12 | 2022-02-15 20:20:12 |

Query for active invoice_items will be as simple as

```
select "invoice_items".* from "invoice_items"
  where "invoice_items"."expiry_date" >= [today's date]
```

This approach should work assuming that existing subscriptions never change (and only new ones with new `subscription_id` get added).